# Prove the following properties of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S$ a field and $A$ a matrix, $(A \in M_{m,n}(K)$) so the rank of A is $dim(im(A))$

$ T \in GL_{m}(K), S \in GL_{n}(K)$ where $GL$ is a general linear group

Prove the properties:

- $ker(TA)=ker(A)$
- $im(AS) = im(A)$
- $dim(ker(TAS))=dim(ker(A))$ and $dim(im(TAS))=dim(im(A))$

After trying to find a solution I find out that

$ker(BS)= \{ S^{-1} \cdot x | x \in ker(B) \} =: S^{-1} \cdot ker(B)$, where $B \in GL_{m,n}(K)$,

but I don't know how to prove it or even that it can help to find a solution to the original properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important fact you should have learned is that every invertible matrix, for example $T \in GL_n (K)$, is such that $\ker T = \{ 0 \}$.  In other words, $Tx = 0 \iff x=0$.  This is a fact worth proving

I will give you the first 2 bullet points, maybe you can deal with the 3rd?

- $\ker (TA) = \{ x : TAx = 0\} = \{ x : Ax = 0\}$ since $T$ is invertible.  But this is exactly the kernel of $A$
- Note that $im (S) = K^n$ since $S$ is an invertible linear map between finite dimensional spaces, hence bijective.  So for any $x$ whose image is $ASx$, there is a $y$ such that $ASx = Ay$. Similarly given any $y$, there is an $x$ such that $Sx=y$ hence $ASx=Ay$.  Namely, $im(AS)=\{ ASx : x \in K^n \} = \{ Ay : y \in K^n \} = im(A) $

I believe the last 2 facts you need to prove use very similar machinery

Comment: to the last property I wrote up that $ im(TB) = {\{T \cdot y | y \in im(B)} = : T \cdot im(b) \} $ but I'm still struggling with the proof